# C#: Block Specific HTML Code

Tags: c#, html, blocking

Let's say that I want to block the specific HTML code

`<script async annoyingcode.js> 
    AnnoyingCodeHere
</script>`

in a website in `WebBrowserControl1`. I tried using `WebClient1.DownloadFile("website.html", @"C:\BlockerWork")`, `File.ReadAllText(@"C:\BlockerWork")`, `String.Replace`, then `WebBrowserControl1.DocumentStream`, but it simply takes too long to run and requires downloading all the time. Is there an easier way in C#?

Comment: Using ASP.NET Web Forms here? If you are stop using ASP.NET Web Forms. 

Whether you are using ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Forms, you should be using Javascript, the client side programming language to solve your issue, not the server side language C#

Comment: Is the html page from your own website or 3rd parties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the file operation by using `WebClient1.DownloadString("website.html")`

Comment: Thanks engineforce for your answer. However, it would be even better if there was something that can block specific HTML code without having to use a download operation. Either way, you're correct!